# NSURLConnection delegate methods not getting called

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, delegates, nsurlconnection

I am having a Server Class which has delegate methods of NSURLConnection. And I am having another class named SendRequest which will send the NSMutableURLRequest to the Server Class. 
In Server Class I am having two methods called

```
- (void)executeAsync:(NSMutableURLRequest)urlRequest timeOutInterval:(int)timeOut
{
    _urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];];
}

- (void)executeSync:(NSMutableURLRequest)urlRequest
{
    NSData* respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest                        returningResponse:&response error:&error];

}
```

Everything works fine until here , I am able to call the above executeAsync method from SendRequest class, which is calling the delegate methods.

Now I have added a new method in the SendRequest class which will call the executeRequest method in Server class.

```
- (void)executeRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest)urlRequest
{
    _urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];];
}
```

This time , I got trapped . executeRequest method is getting called but it is not calling its delegate methods while processing the URL request.  I am struck here for many hours.

Everything seems to be correct , I am sending the urlRequest the same way I used to send before. But I don't know why it is not working. Feel free comment , but please help me. I am really worried

**EDIT :**

I need to post a request to the server and get a response . If I try with synchronous it is working fine,but it is blocking the main thread. Thats the reason I am going for the asynchronous. Through delegate methods I am trying to get the response data.

Comment: Your code here doesn't actually show that you are calling [_urlConnection start]. I assume you are doing that somewhere?

Comment: I have edited my question .Please check it

Comment: He's using the startImmediately option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally solved it. Hope this will help some-one. I made code clean up and declared methods properly and finally while creating the object for the class , I have to use initwithDelegate:self . And finally NSURLConnection delegate methods are called .

Answer (score 1):

I think your description of the system doesn't match the posted code, and it explains the problem you described.  The SendRequest class ought to rely on the Server class to perform the server request.

It looks like the SendRequest class sets the connection delegate to self.  I'm guessing all of those delegate methods are implemented on the Server class.

Try doing what your description suggested....

```
// SendRequest.m

- (void)executeRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest)urlRequest
{
    // however you get ahold of your server...
    Server *myServer = [Server sharedInstance];

    // let it do the work.  it has the delegate methods
    [myServer executeAsync:urlRequest];
}
```

Alternatively, the SendRequest code can stay as it is, but set the delegate to an instance of Server class (again, assuming that's where the delegate methods are implemented).  I think this second idea is worse, since the Server already knows how to start a request.

Comment: Actually I am preparing a large urlRequest, thats why I have posted the prototype only. Ya you are right . The second idea is worse.Actually I tried calling the same executeAsync method again. It is calling , but delegate methods are not called. So I have created a new method for that,I mean executeRequest

Comment: Even I have checked with the objects is nil, everything is perfect.

Comment: Please check my question again, I have mentioned in the last what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I should have suggested you call the other (asynch) method.  But the point is that, whatever else is going on, the object you send the connection as delegate must be the object that implements the delegate methods.  Will edit the answer to call asynch.

Comment: Fine. I am waiting for your reply. I am really getting mad in this issue.

Comment: I've been there.  This stuff can be very frustrating.  I did tweak the code in my solution - to call executeAsync.  I know I am repeating myself, but look at where you set the NSURLConnection delegate... initWithRequest:request delegate:self <--- See.  Who is that self?  NSLog it, to find it's class name.  Now look at that class.  Does that class implement the delegate methods?  Do that in ALL places you call initWithRequest.  I think the one in SendRequest is wrong.

Comment: I am gone mad now. I can't try anymore. Will check it by tomo.

Comment: Sometimes taking a break is the best way to see clearly again.  When you come back to the problem, please review my last comment.  I think you are really close.

Comment: I tried logging the delegate:self for both the cases. It is printing the same class name. Will try with remaining possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

set **NSURLConnectionDelegate** to your .h

then run the following code in .m function

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                                initWithRequest:request
                                       delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] 
                      forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[connection start];
```